# bx slider destroy when less than 4 slides

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm using BX slider on a project and having some trouble with the destroy.slider() method - my client is adding images via a CMS, so there is a variable # of slides for each instance of the slider. I'm trying to kill the slider when there are fewer than 5 slides and return to the normal state of display (which is a grid without any controls). After reading the documentation, I thought this would work, but no luck - the slider stays in tact, even though getSlideCount is returning 2.  Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

```
var slider = $('#view-profiles').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 4,
  maxSlides: 4,
  nextSelector: '.next',
  prevSelector: '.back',
  slideWidth:   '220px',
  pager: false,
  slideMargin: '0',
  nextText: '',
  prevText: '',
  infiniteLoop:false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true



}); 

if (slider.getSlideCount() < 5){
  slider.destroySlider();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var total_slide = slider.getSlideCount() ;

if (total_slide  < 5){
  slider.destroySlider();
}
```

or

```
var slider = $('#view-profiles').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 4,
  maxSlides: 4,
  nextSelector: '.next',
  prevSelector: '.back',
  slideWidth:   '220px',
  pager: false,
  slideMargin: '0',
  nextText: '',
  prevText: '',
  infiniteLoop:false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true,
  onSliderLoad:function() 
            {
            if (slider.getSlideCount() < 5){
            slider.destroySlider();
            }    
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#view-profiles > div').length > 4){
            var slider = $('#view-profiles').bxSlider({
                  minSlides: 4,
                  maxSlides: 4,
                  nextSelector: '.next',
                  prevSelector: '.back',
                  slideWidth:   '220px',
                  pager: false,
                  slideMargin: '0',
                  nextText: '',
                  prevText: '',
                  infiniteLoop:false,
                  hideControlOnEnd: true   
                });
    }
```

Comment: You forgot `slider.destroySlider();`

Comment: @zer00ne if slides  is less than 5 not required to make. why u r destroy it?

Comment: Oh I see my bad. Yours is a min of 4.